# How do wait for factory function to finish and then process output in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wait, q, angular-promise

I have a function in my factory which takes a second to execute, I want the calling function to wait until output has finished before console.log result. When I run the getCases function I don't get a output until I click it a second time. I think I'm using my promises wrong.

```
app.factory('cases', function ($q) {
    return {       
        getCases: function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();

            setTimeout(function(){
                 output = 'aaaa';
                 defer.resolve(output);
            },1000);

            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
});


function CaseloadCtrl($scope, cases){
    $scope.master = {};
    $scope.activePath = null;

    $scope.getCases = function(){
        cases.getCases().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };

}
```

button

```
<button ng-click="getCases()">load cases</button>
```

Comment: This should work... `console.log(data)` would be called after 1 sec. No need for a second click

Comment: Right, see my fiddle below. Can you give us your entire code?

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

new fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/f18taw28/1/

Your version same result.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/f18taw28/2/

Code:

```
 <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<button ng-click="runFunc()">Run Func</button>
 </div> 

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.factory("cases", ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        getCases: function () {
         var defer = $q.defer();

        setTimeout(function(){
             output = 'aaaa';
             defer.resolve(output);
        },500);

        return defer.promise;
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $q, cases) {
  $scope.runFunc = function(){
      $q.when(cases.getCases()).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
   });
  };
});
```

Comment: Strange your fiddle is working fine but when I use the code, the status doesn't update until I click a button even if the button doesn't do anything? 

{{status}}
<button ng-click="">load cases</button>

Comment: ok, I'll check on your specific case. I should have done that anyways. I'll post a new fiddle.

Comment: @MattH please check new fiddle.

Comment: I think my problem is that Im using angular 1.0.7. In your fiddle it works perfectly but if you change it angular 1.1.1 it stops working. So im guessing thats my problem. If I try to change my version to 1.2.1 like your fiddle I get "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=CrudApp&p1=Error%3A…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.1%2Fangular.min.js%3A32%3A462)" Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Brilliant its working now I just needed to include the angular route cdn. Cheers mate

Comment: Awesome! That's what matters!